# Finding functions within code using Regex python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract all the functions I have in a file using REGEX.
Here's a standard file example:

```
int main()
{
    printf("hello to all the good people");
    printf("hello to all the good people %d ", GetLastError());

    for(int i =0; i<15; i++)
    {
        if(i == 5)
        {
            switch(i)
            {
                case 0:
                    break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the meantime, I have only succeeded in capturing functions using the following REGEX:

```
regex = re.findall('\w+\s*?[(].*[)]', _content) #'\w+\s*?[(]*[)]'
for i in regex:
    print i
```

My problems are:

1. How can I tell him to ignore things like FOR or SWITCH?
2. How do I tell him to find an internal function inside an externally as an example:

`printf ("%s", get_string());`

3. How do I make it not to relate to `()` that are between quotes as `()` that aren't between quotes (so if i have line:
   `printf("hello to j. (and rona) %s", get_family_name());`
   he will know to extract:

   `foo name:                      parameters:
   printf                          "hello to j. (and rona) %s", get_family_name()
   get_family_name                 none`

Comment: do you need to use regex?

Comment: you can filter out for and switch after if you find a regex that works, though I think creating a parser would work better

Comment: i think that regex is the best tool for this kind of mission , it's just filtering text...

Comment: You are wrong, Yoram. While I am a big fan of regexes they are the wrong tool for parsing things like HTML or computer languages. A regex is often good enough when searching for a function definition inside your editor but is not robust enough for any non-interactive use.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse C using regular expressions.

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/5951320) about parsing HTML with regex; the answer given there applies also to C, and to essentially any useful programming language.

The [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) library looks like it might be useful, particularly the [func_calls example](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/func_calls.py) – in fact, I think the following snippet (adapted from that example) will do exactly what you want, although I haven't tested it:

```
from pycparser import c_ast, parse_file

class FuncCallVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncCall(self, node):
        print("{} called at {}".format(node.name.name, node.name.coord))

ast = parse_file("myfile.c", use_cpp=True)
v = FuncCallVisitor()
v.visit(ast)
```